# How to get Serial Port profile SDP record for remote device

Tags: c++, windows-ce

I am trying to write an application that pairs a remote bluetooth device with Windows Mobile/CE handheld and get the service of the device.

I noticed that when you manually pair a device and set the service through the system(eg. go to settings->Bluetooth-> add device) it generates an *sdprecord* value in the following registry

HKLM/Software/Microsoft/Bluetooth/Device/*{deviceAddress}*/{*Service_UUID*}.

I am basically trying to implement this in my program.

I followed the following documentations:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms883458.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms883398.aspx

and then convert the SDPrecord into binary and write it to the registry:

```
RegSetValueEx(hSerialPortKey,_T("sdprecord"),0,REG_BINARY,(BYTE*)&pRecord,sizeof(pRecord)*2+1);
```

The result is not the same as what I would get when I manually pair the device.

What am I doing wrong? How can I retrieve the SDP record? Thank you in advance.

Below is my code

```
BTHNS_RESTRICTIONBLOB RBlob;
memset(&RBlob,0,sizeof(BTHNS_RESTRICTIONBLOB));
RBlob.type = SDP_SERVICE_SEARCH_ATTRIBUTE_REQUEST;
RBlob.numRange = 1;
RBlob.uuids[0].uuidType= SDP_ST_UUID16;//SDP_ST_UUID128;
RBlob.uuids[0].u.uuid16= SerialPortServiceClassID_UUID16;
RBlob.pRange[0].minAttribute =SDP_ATTRIB_PROTOCOL_DESCRIPTOR_LIST;
RBlob.pRange[0].maxAttribute = SDP_ATTRIB_PROTOCOL_DESCRIPTOR_LIST;

SOCKADDR_BTH sa;
memset (&sa, 0, sizeof(SOCKADDR_BTH));
BTH_ADDR *pDeviceAddr = &devAddress;
*(BTH_ADDR *)(&sa.btAddr) = *pDeviceAddr;
sa.addressFamily = AF_BTH;

CSADDR_INFO csai;
memset(&csai,0,sizeof(CSADDR_INFO));
csai.RemoteAddr.lpSockaddr = (sockaddr*)&sa;
csai.RemoteAddr.iSockaddrLength = sizeof(sa);

BLOB blob;
blob.cbSize = sizeof(BTHNS_RESTRICTIONBLOB);
blob.pBlobData = (BYTE *)&RBlob;

WSAQUERYSET wsaq;
memset(&wsaq,0,sizeof(WSAQUERYSET));
wsaq.dwSize = sizeof(WSAQUERYSET);
wsaq.dwNumberOfCsAddrs = 1;
wsaq.dwNameSpace = NS_BTH;
wsaq.lpBlob = &blob;
wsaq.lpcsaBuffer = &csai;
wsaq.lpServiceClassId = &serialPortUUID;

//Initialising winsock
    WSADATA data;
    int result = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &data);//initializing winsock
    if (hLib == NULL)
    {
        return S_FALSE;
    }
    result =  WSALookupServiceBegin (&wsaq,0, &hLookup);
    while (result ==ERROR_SUCCESS )
    {
        BYTE sdpBuffer[4096];
        memset(sdpBuffer,0,sizeof(sdpBuffer));
        LPWSAQUERYSET pResult = (LPWSAQUERYSET)&sdpBuffer;
        dwSize = sizeof(sdpBuffer);
        pResult->dwSize = sizeof(WSAQUERYSET);
        pResult->dwNameSpace = NS_BTH;
        pResult->lpBlob = NULL;
        pResult->lpServiceClassId = &serialPortUUID;
        result = WSALookupServiceNext(hLookup,0,&dwSize,pResult);
        if(result == -1 )
        {
            int error;
            error = WSAGetLastError();
            if (error == WSA_E_NO_MORE)
                break;
        }
        else
        {
            //Get SDP record
            if (pResult != NULL)
            {
                if (ERROR_SUCCESS != ServiceAndAttributeSearchParse(pResult->lpBlob->pBlobData,pResult->lpBlob->cbSize,&pRecordArg,&ulRecords)) { //error handling}
                ULONG recordIndex;
                for (recordIndex = 0; recordIndex < ulRecords; recordIndex++) {
                    pRecord = pRecordArg[recordIndex];}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the code should be ok.Here's my code

```
int FindRFCOMMChannel (unsigned char *pStream, int cStream, unsigned char *pChann) 
{ 
    ISdpRecord **pRecordArg; 
    int cRecordArg = 0; 

    *pChann = 0; 

    int hr = ServiceAndAttributeSearch(pStream, cStream, &pRecordArg, (ULONG *)&cRecordArg); 

    if (hr != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        BT_ERROR( CBTRFCOMMMgr, PerformServiceSearch, "ServiceAndAttributeSearch ERROR %d\n");    
        return hr; 
    }

    for (int i = 0; (! *pChann) && (i < cRecordArg); i++) 
    { 
        ISdpRecord *pRecord = pRecordArg[i];    // particular record to examine in this loop 
        CNodeDataFreeString protocolList;     // contains SDP_ATTRIB_PROTOCOL_DESCRIPTOR_LIST data, if available 

        if (ERROR_SUCCESS != pRecord->GetAttribute(SDP_ATTRIB_PROTOCOL_DESCRIPTOR_LIST,&protocolList) || 
            (protocolList.type != SDP_TYPE_CONTAINER)) 
            continue; 

        ISdpNodeContainer *pRecordContainer = protocolList.u.container; 
        int cProtocols = 0; 
        NodeData protocolDescriptor; // information about a specific protocol (i.e. L2CAP, RFCOMM, ...) 

        pRecordContainer->GetNodeCount((DWORD *)&cProtocols); 
        for (int j = 0; (! *pChann) && (j < cProtocols); j++) { 
            pRecordContainer->GetNode(j,&protocolDescriptor); 

            if (protocolDescriptor.type != SDP_TYPE_CONTAINER) 
                continue; 

            ISdpNodeContainer *pProtocolContainer = protocolDescriptor.u.container; 
            int cProtocolAtoms = 0; 
            pProtocolContainer->GetNodeCount((DWORD *)&cProtocolAtoms); 

            for (int k = 0; (! *pChann) && (k < cProtocolAtoms); k++) { 
                NodeData nodeAtom;  // individual data element, such as what protocol this is or RFCOMM channel id. 

                pProtocolContainer->GetNode(k,&nodeAtom); 

                if (IsRfcommUuid(&nodeAtom))  { 
                    if (k+1 == cProtocolAtoms) { 
                        // misformatted response.  Channel ID should follow RFCOMM uuid 
                        break; 
                    } 

                    NodeData channelID; 
                    pProtocolContainer->GetNode(k+1,&channelID); 

                    *pChann = (unsigned char)GetChannel(&channelID); 
                    break; // formatting error 
                } 
            } 
        } 
    } 

    for (i = 0; i < cRecordArg; i++)  
        pRecordArg[i]->Release(); 

    CoTaskMemFree(pRecordArg); 

    return (*pChann != 0) ? 1:0; 
} 

int IsRfcommUuid(NodeData *pNode)  { 
if (pNode->type != SDP_TYPE_UUID) 
    return FALSE; 

if (pNode->specificType == SDP_ST_UUID16) 
    return (pNode->u.uuid16 == RFCOMM_PROTOCOL_UUID16); 
else if (pNode->specificType == SDP_ST_UUID32) 
    return (pNode->u.uuid32 == RFCOMM_PROTOCOL_UUID16); 
else if (pNode->specificType == SDP_ST_UUID128) 
    return (0 == memcmp(&RFCOMM_PROTOCOL_UUID,&pNode->u.uuid128,sizeof(GUID))); 

return FALSE; 
} 

int GetChannel (NodeData *pChannelNode) { 
if (pChannelNode->specificType == SDP_ST_UINT8) 
    return pChannelNode->u.uint8; 
else if (pChannelNode->specificType == SDP_ST_INT8) 
    return pChannelNode->u.int8; 
else if (pChannelNode->specificType == SDP_ST_UINT16) 
    return pChannelNode->u.uint16; 
else if (pChannelNode->specificType == SDP_ST_INT16) 
    return pChannelNode->u.int16; 
else if (pChannelNode->specificType == SDP_ST_UINT32) 
    return pChannelNode->u.uint32; 
else if (pChannelNode->specificType == SDP_ST_INT32) 
    return pChannelNode->u.int32; 

return 0; 
}
```